# Intersection function returns multiple coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates, intersection, shapely

I am trying to find intersection vertices of two polygons defined below

```
PG = Polygon([(0.0,0.0), (0.0,4.0), (2.0, 0.0)])
QG = shapely.affinity.rotate(PG, 10.0, origin="centroid")
print(PG.intersection(QG))
```

It returns a polygon which represents the intersection vertices but I get multiple vertices belonging to polygon PG and QG and not the exact intersection vertices something like this

```
POLYGON ((0 1.275007557649384, 0 3.233068398870882, 1.176669689726421 1.646660620547158, 1.901423900453083 0.1971521990938349, 0.7833182180345657 0, 0.2248182330207899 0, 0 1.275007557649384))
```

The graph looks something like this[image]

How to get the exact coordinates of intersection vertices **A, B and C** as shown above?

Comment: Intersection of two overlapping polygons is a polygon. Are you perhaps more interested in finding the intersection of the boundaries of the polygons (linear rings) that would give a multipoint in this case?

Comment: I am interested in getting just the intersection coordinates of polygons PG and QG.

Comment: the vertices of the polygon are the points you want, aren't they? other wise can you mark on your image which points you do want

Comment: There are 3 intersection coordinates if you see the above graph where both the polygons intersect. I want to find the coordinates of those 3 points.

Comment: I can see 6 points where the boundaries of the two polygons intersect. Could you mark your favorites? Polygons intersect topologically also in all interior points which are common for both and obviously you are not interested in that.

Comment: I can't imagine how just those 3 points could be selected and 3 other points where the boundaries intersect as well not. Or perhaps "intersection points of the boundary segments which have the longest distance from start and end points of the segments" could do that.

Comment: You will have to process the single lines of your boundaries separately and have some kind of identifier for which is which (assuming you always have such "same but affinity transformed" geometries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) says, the intersection of two overlapping polygons is a polygon and with your result (light blue polygon)

[image]

The intersection of the boundaries of the polygons (linearRings) gives a multipoint in you case

```
one = LineString(list(PG.exterior.coords))
two = LineString(list(QG.exterior.coords))
print(one.intersection(two).wkt)
MULTIPOINT (0 1.275007557649384, 0 3.233068398870882, 0.2248182330207899 0, 0.7833182180345657 0, 1.176669689726421 1.646660620547158, 1.901423900453083 0.1971521990938349)
```

[image]

These points are also the vertices of the resulting polygon

```
points = [Point(pt) for pt in list(PG.intersection(QG).exterior.coords)[:-1]]
for i in points:
     print(i.wkt)
POINT (0 1.275007557649384)
POINT (0 3.233068398870882)
POINT (1.176669689726421 1.646660620547158)
POINT (1.901423900453083 0.1971521990938349)
POINT (0.7833182180345657 0)
POINT (0.2248182330207899 0)
```

[image]

But shapely alone does not allow to  select the A,B,C points from the others.